# Boundary value problem: boundedness of solution

Tags: proof-verification, boundary-value-problem

I have this (decoupled) BVP (where $\lambda <0$):

$y_1'(t) = \lambda y_1(t) \\
y_2'(t) = - \lambda y_2(t) \\
y_1(0) = 1, \quad  y_2(a)=1$

for $t \in [0,a]$. It has been written in the notes that the BVP is stable since the solution $y_1(t) = e^{\lambda t},  y_2(t) =e^{a \lambda } e^{-\lambda t} $ remains bounded for $t \to \infty$.

I want to know how is $y_2(t)$ bounded as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: It doesn't, for example take $a=1$ and $\lambda=-1$. Then $y_2(t)=e^{t-1}$.

Comment: Ok. I thought it should be wrong. Thanks.